# Plank dock shows read-only error in terminal

Tags: elementary-os, readonly, plank

When I run **[plank](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Plank/)** dock in the terminal console I see the following errors popping up:

```
[WARN ...] [Preferences:192] '/usr/share/themes/io.elementary.stylesheet.blueberry/plank/dock.theme' is read-only!
[WARN ...] [Preferences:378] Missing key 'UrgentHueShift' for group 'PlankDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/themes/io.elementary.stylesheet.blueberry/plank/dock.theme' - using default value
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

To **fix** these two problems enter:

```
sudo chmod 666 /usr/share/themes/io.elementary.stylesheet.*/plank/dock.theme
```

Note with the * we´ll also catch the stylesheets
banana, blueberry ... strawberry

The error:

```
Missing key 'UrgentHueShift' for group 'PlankDockTheme'
```

will be fixed as well since now plank can save the file and set the missing setting.

Well before I ran the "change file mode bits" I check with:

```
ls -al /usr/share/themes/io.elementary.stylesheet.blueberry/plank/dock.theme
```

the current settings:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2600 Apr 25 20:31 /usr/share/themes/io.elementary.stylesheet.blueberry/plank/dock.theme
```

So the file is owned by **root** (with read write access right) but used by **user** (in the group others last 'r--' with the read-only right)

Well some other approach is to change the owner from **root** to **tux**. (Replace tux with your username!)

```
sudo chown tux:tux /usr/share/themes/io.elementary.stylesheet.*/plank/dock.theme
```

*Maybe this create some problems if apt-get ( or under the hood it`s dpkg doing the job) likes to update or remove these files but fails because of missing access permissions. However I have not tested if that is the case.*